# Initializing array of typed arrays in razor page

Tags: c#, arrays, razor, blazor, jagged-arrays

Here, I am trying to instantiate and initialize a custom-typed array to bind it in **Blazor's component**.
It is Kind of array of arrays. But are typed and the first one is encapsulated in a class.

The first level typed collection class (LinkArray):

```
public class LinkArray
{
        // constructor will automatically generate the addresses if not given
        public LinkArray(string[] params links)
        { ... }

        public Link[] Links { get; set; }

        public Link Header { get; set; } 

}
```

Link class:

```
public class Link
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Initialization in the **.razor file's code section**:

```
    @code{
    //LinkArray[] allColz;

    // Method 1 : creating LinkArrays individually, and then trying to add each 
    // It has a constructor that can handle it via just passing the first parameter
    LinkArray firstCol = new LinkArray("asd","asdasd","asdasd");
    LinkArray secondCol = new LinkArray("asd","asdasd","asdasda","asdasd");

    //LinkArray[] allColz = new LinkArray[] { 'firstCol', 'secondCol' };
    List<LinkArray> allColz = new List<LinkArray>() { 'How to add firstCol & secondCol here');
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<CustomComp AllColz="@allColz" />
```

How to initialize and fill allColz with the firstCol & secondCol shown above?

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to make it clearer what you're trying to do, what problems you are encountering. At present it's just a bit too vague

Comment: @Quango ah OK, I was sleepless with headache, will narrow down the problem or maybe re-create the topic.

Comment: @Quango done, now simplified. The only question is in the last line.

Comment: @Kasrak I'm not entirely sure what a LinkArray is. Is this from the razor library or the blazor library? I can't seem to find anything on it. If however that's one of your types you created, can you share that too?

Comment: @Urasquirrel LInkArray is the first code extracted posted here, I mentioned its name in the upper line of that code block, now will edit the code block, so guess you will find it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the first level of data arrays into `static`

```
static LinkArray firstCol = new LinkArray("asd","asdasd","asdasd");
static LinkArray secondCol = new LinkArray("asd","asdasd","asdasda","asdasd");
```

and then added by the following line:

```
LinkArray[] allColz = new LinkArray[] {firstCol, secondCol };
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage is pretty straightforward:

```html
<CustomComp AllColz="@allColz" />
```

So in your component code should be

```cs
[Parameter] List<LinkArray> AllColz {get;set;}
```

See [parameter reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-parameters)

I'm not clear why you're setting up this property in the component code. If you want to create the value in the component and then access it externally (e.g. from a parent component) then you might want to use a method that returns the value, instead of using a `Parameter`, e.g.

```cs
@code 
{
   public List<LinkArray> GetAllColz() 
   {
     return allColz;
   }
}
```

Comment: My issue is exactly the parts you omitted. @allColz can not be filled via GetAllColz() , right? how can we do that? In another hand I expect you fill allColz with the real data, cause that is part of my question here. thanks

Comment: My issue here was about the "Array Initialization" with the data, you can provide the example code in the 'component code' or show how to bound to your GetAllColz. but I need the full array initialization with the data.

Comment: OK, you are filling and initializing the data inside "GetAllColz()", right? No problem on it. Now how AllColz="@allColz" will fire "GetAllColz()" ?